# Sum in rows some other column rows values grouped by other column ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql, sum

Is it possible to do a query like this? I have the ID, some IN value, Out value and the last column TOTAL is the sum of the difference between IN and OUT. I just really need the complete sum. 
The ID2 rows that are equals must be summed in the SUM column. There is no ID2 quantity fixed, some times it would be just one row to sum, other cases there will be more. I could also add a difference column, to just sum the value in that row for the same ID2.

My doubt here is, is it possible to sum in a row, the accumulated in some rows at other columns?

```
ID  ID2 IN  OUT TOTAL (IN-OUT)
1   2   200 150 blank-null-space-or whatever but a character
2   2   350 250 doesn't matter, also it can have the same SUM result as below
3   2   600 400 350 ( = 200 - 150 + 350 - 250 + 600 - 400)
4   3   100  80  20
```

Or I have to do it at the client side in JavaScript? Which is better or you do suggest? Maybe it is easier in JavaScript but I wanted to do it all in one step to reduce the pool connections.

A simple verifiable example would be

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
  "ID" int NOT NULL,
  "ID2" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "`EXT_ID" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "IN" int DEFAULT NULL
  "OUT" int DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "table1" ("ID", "ID2", "EXT_ID", "IN", "OUT") VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 200, 150),
(2, 2, 2, 350, 250),
(3, 2, 2, 600, 400),
(4, 3, 4, 100,  80),
(5, 3, 5, 130, 100),
(6, 4, 6, 100,  80),
(7, 4, 7, 120,  70),
(8, 4, 7, 150,  90);
```

**EDIT**: Added an foreign ID column "EXT_ID" that have a condition show only one row and the one that has MAX value from the same "ID2".

Corrected SQL syntax.

Comment: Hi, Carlos. You change the question. Is better for stackoverflow to post a new question. In that way there be preserved the right answers to the original question.

Comment: Ok, Do you suggest to revert the edit?

Comment: It is not really necessary to reverse it

Comment: Your `create table` command uses `MySQL` syntax and the tag is `Postgresql`. Which one?

Comment: Corrected SQL syntax. Is Postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited

Yes, it is posible. You can use group by (if you only want the total)

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
  "ID" int NOT NULL,
  "ID2" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "EXT_ID" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "IN" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "OUT" int DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "table1" ("ID", "ID2", "EXT_ID", "IN", "OUT") VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 200, 150),
(2, 2, 2, 350, 250),
(3, 2, 2, 600, 400),
(4, 3, 4, 100,  80),
(5, 3, 5, 130, 100),
(6, 4, 6, 100,  80),
(7, 4, 7, 120,  70),
(8, 4, 7, 150,  90);

select "ID2", sum("IN" - "OUT")
  from "table1"
  group by "ID2";
```

[image: result 1]

#### Old answer:

Yes, it is posible. You can use window functions

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
  "ID" int NOT NULL,
  "ID2" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "IN" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "OUT" int DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "table1" ("ID", "ID2", "IN", "OUT") VALUES
(1, 2, 200, 150),
(2, 2, 350, 250),
(3, 2, 600, 400),
(4, 3, 100,  80);

select * , sum("IN" - "OUT") over (partition by "ID2" order by "ID")
  from "table1"
  order by "ID2", "ID";
```

[image: result 2]

As you see in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

A functional example: http://rextester.com/OVCTC74070

Comment: mmm Ok, I didn't know about this function, let me see and read the docs.. thanks, this will give me some other point of view.

Comment: Ok this is the one that most solved the question. But I did not explain very well myself since the beginning, so I'm still facing some trouble because in my actual env, i want to filter to get only the most recent data since last week and from the past last week, but that's another topic.. thanks @emilio-platzer

Comment: Ask it. We will help you.

Comment: ok, thanks. let me prepare it. I saw your profile, i speak spanish too, it is easier to me to explain myself it that language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915437/get-the-only-latest-data-from-last-week-and-sum-some-column, also took my time to make a full example.. if you could help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```
select (SUM(`IN` - `OUT`)) as 'Total' 
from (
  select * 
  from table1
  where ID2 IN (select ID2 from table1 where ID = "3")
) as temptable;
```

but this can only get result of 1 row, you might have to edit it.

Comment: Ok, this give me an idea, i could use this "N" times and using `UNION ALL` between each other. Even this will cost make another query and join them in JavaScript. Thanks!!