# Get the only latest data from last week and sum some column

Tags: postgresql, distinct

Get only latest data from last week and sum some column

I made an example with dat, the actual result and the expected.

http://rextester.com/HMB12638

```
 --Taking first as example..

--      user    contact         barcode date                in  out dif
-- 1    USER2   Guillermo Tole  987654  16.06.2017 05:27:00 500 420 80
-- 2    USER2   Guillermo Tole  281460  15.06.2017 05:36:00 310 220 90
-- 3    USER2   Guillermo Tole  987654  13.06.2017 05:27:00 400 380 20
-- 4    USER2   Guillermo Tole  281460  12.06.2017 05:26:00 230 190 40
-- 5    USER3   Juan Rulfo      123456  15.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150
-- 6    USER3   Juan Rulfo      123456  12.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150
-- 7    USER3   Pepito Marquez  346234  15.06.2017 05:37:00 600 360 240
-- 8    USER3   Pepito Marquez  346234  14.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150


 -- This would be the expectation
-- (MOST RECENT in . out) SUM of all the barcodes showed
--      user    contact         barcode date                in  out sum
-- 1    USER2   Guillermo Tole  987654  16.06.2017 05:27:00 500 420 170 (80 + 90)
-- 2    USER2   Guillermo Tole  281460  15.06.2017 05:36:00 310 220 170 (80 + 90)
-- 5    USER3   Juan Rulfo      123456  15.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150
-- 7    USER3   Pepito Marquez  346234  15.06.2017 05:37:00 600 360 240
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this matches your expected result:

```
select "user", "contact", "barcode", "date", "in", "out","dif"
     , sum("in"-"out") over(partition by "user", "contact") as "sum"
from (
    select "user", "contact", "barcode", "date", "in", "out","dif"
    , lag(dif,1) over(partition by "user", "contact" order by "date" ASC) prevdif
    , row_number() over(partition by "user", "contact" order by "date" DESC) rn
    from "table1" 
    where date_trunc('day', "date") <= '2017-06-25' ::date - (  interval '1 week')::interval 
    and "date" >  '2017-06-25'::date - (  interval '2 weeks')::interval 
    ) d
where rn in (1,2) and prevdif is not null
order by 1,2,4 DESC
```

Result:

```
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    | user  |    contact     | barcode |        date         | in  | out | dif | sum |
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | USER2 | Guillermo Tole |  987654 | 16.06.2017 05:27:00 | 500 | 420 |  80 | 170 |
|  2 | USER2 | Guillermo Tole |  281460 | 15.06.2017 05:36:00 | 310 | 220 |  90 | 170 |
|  3 | USER3 | Juan Rulfo     |  123456 | 15.06.2017 05:37:00 | 450 | 300 | 150 | 150 |
|  4 | USER3 | Pepito Marquez |  346234 | 15.06.2017 05:37:00 | 600 | 360 | 240 | 240 |
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

See: http://rextester.com/ISHS42170

For conditions such as "most recent" I find that using ROW_NUMBER() OVER() is the most convenient as it allows the whole row of each "most recent" event be returned which isn't quite so simple if using MAX() and GROUP BY. "Distinct" results are returned by filtering the rows having value 1 returned by the function.

---

**+EDIT**

Instead of using `where rn in (1,2)` I believe a better way would have been better to use barcode in the OVER(PARTITION BY...) conditions, like this:

```
select "user", "contact", "barcode", "date", "in", "out","dif"
     , sum("in"-"out") over(partition by "user", "contact") as "sum"
from (
    select "user", "contact", "barcode", "date", "in", "out","dif"
    , lag(dif,1) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC) prevdif
    , row_number() over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" DESC) rn
    from "table1" 
    where date_trunc('day', "date") <= '2017-06-25' ::date - (  interval '1 week')::interval 
    and "date" >  '2017-06-25'::date - (  interval '2 weeks')::interval 
    ) d
where rn = 1 and prevdif is not null
order by 1,2,4 DESC
```

http://rextester.com/SCV98254

Comment: this is just.. awesome! I'm not an expert in this area

Comment: ok, i've been testing with this, and, if i change from 1 - 2 week to 1-3,4,5,etc weeks, it brings duplicate barcode results, and I just want the last one.

Comment: you can test mine, it doesn't bring duplicate barcodes, just the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

Made it.. just in case somebody need it, it may not be the most elegant work, but at least it works

```
-- create a table and keep the IDs you want the info
with tabla as (
    SELECT distinct on( barcode) barcode  as barcode, id, date
    from table1 as tabla
    where date_trunc('day', date) <= '2017-06-25' ::date - (interval '1 week')::interval 
 and date >  '2017-06-25'::date - (interval '2 weeks')::interval
    order by barcode, date desc
) 
-- make the query using inner join on the previously created table
select user, contact, t1.barcode, t1.date, "in", out, dif ,  sum("in" - out) over (partition by contact order by t1.barcode)
    from table1 t1 
      inner join tabla on tabla.id = t1.id
    where date_trunc('day', t1.date) <= '2017-06-25' ::date - (interval '1 week')::interval 
 and t1.date >  '2017-06-25'::date - (interval '2 weeks')::interval 
 order by contact, barcode, date desc
 -- PD, "in" is a reserved word, i have to keep it with commas
```