# Get only latest data from last week and past last week and sum some column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Get only latest data from last week and sum some column

I made an example with dat, the actual result and the expected.

http://rextester.com/HMB12638

```
--Taking an example kind of like this..

--      user    contact         barcode date                in  out dif
-- 1    USER2   Guillermo Tole  987654  16.06.2017 05:27:00 500 420 80
-- 2    USER2   Guillermo Tole  281460  15.06.2017 05:36:00 310 220 90
-- 3    USER2   Guillermo Tole  987654  13.06.2017 05:27:00 400 380 20
-- 4    USER2   Guillermo Tole  281460  12.06.2017 05:26:00 230 190 40
-- 5    USER3   Juan Rulfo      123456  15.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150
-- 6    USER3   Juan Rulfo      123456  12.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150
-- 7    USER3   Pepito Marquez  346234  15.06.2017 05:37:00 600 360 240
-- 8    USER3   Pepito Marquez  346234  14.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150
```

This is my actual result using  this query.

First. Create a table and keep the IDs you want the info

```
with tabla as (
    SELECT distinct on( barcode) barcode  as barcode, id, date
    from table1 as tabla
    where date_trunc('day', date) <= '2017-06-25' ::date - (interval '1 week')::interval 
 and date >  '2017-06-25'::date - (interval '2 weeks')::interval
    order by barcode, date desc
)
```

Then make the query using inner join on the previously created table

```
select user, contact, t1.barcode, t1.date, "in", out, dif ,  sum("in" - out) over (partition by contact order by t1.barcode)
    from table1 t1 
      inner join tabla on tabla.id = t1.id
    where date_trunc('day', t1.date) <= '2017-06-25' ::date - (interval '1 week')::interval 
 and t1.date >  '2017-06-25'::date - (interval '2 weeks')::interval 
 order by contact, barcode, date desc
 -- PD, "in" is a reserved word, i have to keep it with commas
```

This is the result i get using previous query.

```
--      user    contact         barcode date                in  out sum
-- 1    USER2   Guillermo Tole  987654  16.06.2017 05:27:00 500 420 170 (80 + 90)
-- 2    USER2   Guillermo Tole  281460  15.06.2017 05:36:00 310 220 170 (80 + 90)
-- 5    USER3   Juan Rulfo      123456  15.06.2017 05:37:00 450 300 150
-- 7    USER3   Pepito Marquez  346234  15.06.2017 05:37:00 600 360 240
```

This is the expected result, sometimes there won't be data from 2 weeks ago and do will be data from last week, in that case it can be null or empty the this week, and this also can happen viceversa (from last week).

```
    --                                      | 2 weeks ago-----------------| | last week ------------------|
    --      user    contact         barcode date                in  out sum date                in  out sum     
    -- 1    USER2   Guillermo Tole  987654  8.06.2017 05:27:00  500 420 170 15.06.2017 05:27:00 600 550 100 
    -- 2    USER2   Guillermo Tole  281460  6.06.2017 05:36:00  310 220 170 16.06.2017 05:27:00 400 350 100
    -- 5    USER3   Juan Rulfo      123456  9.06.2017 05:37:00  450 300 150 14.06.2017 05:27:00 650 350 300
    -- 7    USER3   Pepito Marquez  346234  7.06.2017 05:37:00  600 360 240 15.06.2017 05:27:00 750 500 250
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915437/get-the-only-latest-data-from-last-week-and-sum-some-column) which now works (correctly I believe) by including barcode into the OVER() clause of LAG() and ROW_NUMBER().

```
select "user", "contact", "barcode", "prev2date", "prev2in", "prev2out","prev2dif", "prev1date", "prev1in", "prev1out","prev1dif"
     , sum("prev1in"-"prev1out") over(partition by "user", "contact") as "sum"
from (
    select "user", "contact", "barcode", "date", "in", "out","dif"
    , lag("date",2) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev2date
    , lag("in"  ,2) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev2in
    , lag("out" ,2) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev2out
    , lag("dif" ,2) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev2dif
    , lag("date",1) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev1date
    , lag("in"  ,1) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev1in
    , lag("out" ,1) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev1out
    , lag("dif" ,1) over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" ASC)  prev1dif
    , row_number()  over(partition by "user", "contact", "barcode" order by "date" DESC) rn
    from "table1" 
    ) d
where rn = 1 and prev1dif is not null
order by 1,2,4 DESC
```

From your sample data, using the query above I got this result:

```
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+-----+
|    | user  |    contact     | barcode |      prev2date      | prev2in | prev2out | prev2dif |      prev1date      | prev1in | prev1out | prev1dif | sum |
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | USER2 | Guillermo Tole |  987654 | 23.06.2017 05:27:00 | 700     | 690      | 10       | 28.06.2017 05:27:00 |     800 |      760 |       40 | 120 |
|  2 | USER2 | Guillermo Tole |  281460 | 15.06.2017 05:36:00 | 310     | 220      | 90       | 20.06.2017 09:37:00 |     490 |      410 |       80 | 120 |
|  3 | USER3 | Juan Rulfo     |  123456 | NULL                | NULL    | NULL     | NULL     | 12.06.2017 05:37:00 |     450 |      300 |      150 | 150 |
|  4 | USER3 | Pepito Marquez |  346234 | 27.06.2017 05:37:00 | 900     | 690      | 210      | 30.06.2017 05:37:00 |    1050 |      900 |      150 | 150 |
+----+-------+----------------+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+-----+
```

http://rextester.com/WODBE20956

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes it is the continue from other question, i really appreciate, now I made some observations think row 4 is wrong, both dates are from the same week,  in row 2 that barcode has data from last week and it is showing data from 2 and 3 weeks ago.. in row 3 is showing data from 3 weeks ago, that should be on left "columns"